# Mostrar password de usuario en frontend Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

vengo con otra preguntita interesante y que no encuentro respuesta.
Dispongo de un custom login page donde se puede cambiar, usando ajax, nuestra información. El tema es que en el front-page he implementado un cambio de contraseña en caso de que te olvides de ella, y claro, luego debes de poder cambiarla en tu custom login.

Para ello he intentado usar la función de wordpress

```
$curret_user->user_pass;
```

pero me muestra algo asi:

$P$BPuB4JSblULb3gQRjLOlbO39/Fqw6r/

y lo que quiero es que la muestre desencriptada.
Alguien me puede orientar en esto

Comment: Para desencriptar la contraseña debes utilizar el mismo método que estés usando para encriptarla (o wordpress en su defecto). En cualquier caso permíteme disuadirte. Nunca hay que mostrar una contraseña de usuario a este mismo si ya ha sido almacenada, por múltiples motivos de seguridad.

Comment: Bueno, eso es correcto, pero por lo menos debo de poder crear un sistema de cambio de contraseña que NO modifica la encriptacion. Es decir, que el usuario escriba perro, y en el momento de guardar, la encripte.

Comment: ¿Y por que no encriptas la nueva contraseña y la guardas en sustitución de la antigua? Si necesitas hacer que el usuario introduzca la contraseña antigua, en vez de desencriptar la que tienes en la base de datos, creo que sería más seguro encriptarla y compararla a la que tienes en la base de datos para ver si coinciden.

Comment: Oh, eso es una manera mas inteligente de actuar. Acabo de emepezar como quien dice y a veces no encuentro la manera mas logina. Gracias, lo voy a intentar, espero que pueda hacerlo